# Sending email with PKCS12 to IOS

Tags: encryption, jakarta-mail, bouncycastle, smime

I have a a problem, I trying to send a message with encryptation FKCS12 and signed, I am using BouncyCastle to encrypt the Message with the Certificate (.cer) file, and signning it with a .pb12 file, the problem is this:

Some diveces such as black berry, android, outlook at windows, even Mac OSX can open an email, but when they try to open the email with IOS (an Iphone 4) they cannot see the content, only can see a message telling that "the email message is encrypted, to can see it you need to install an identity containing its identity encryption".

I think the Java process sending the email It is OK.

¿Any ideas?

BTW, this is the code:

```
MailcapCommandMap mailcap = (MailcapCommandMap)CommandMap
                .getDefaultCommandMap();

        mailcap
                .addMailcap("application/pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_signature");
        mailcap
                .addMailcap("application/pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_mime");
        mailcap
                .addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_signature");
        mailcap
                .addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_mime");
        mailcap
                .addMailcap("multipart/signed;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.multipart_signed");

        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mailcap);
        /*
         * FIN MAILCAP AGREGADO
         */

        args = new String[6];
        args[0] = "ITtest.p12";
        args[1] = "pass";
        args[2] = "1.1.1.example";
        args[3] = "ManuelRodriguez.cer"; //certificado
        args[4] = "noreply_sistemas@siman.com"; //from
        args[5] = "daniel_hernandez@siman.com,omar_rodriguez@siman.com"; //to
        //args[5] = "daniel_hernandez@siman.com,omar_rodriguez@siman.com, manuel_rodriguez@siman.com"; //to

        //
        // Open the key store
        //      
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
        ks.load(Pivote.class.getResourceAsStream("ITtest.p12"), "pass".toCharArray());

        Enumeration e = ks.aliases();
        String      keyAlias = null;

        while (e.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String  alias = (String)e.nextElement();

            if (ks.isKeyEntry(alias))
            {
                keyAlias = alias;
            }
        }

        if (keyAlias == null)
        {
            System.err.println("can't find a private key!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Certificate[]   chain = ks.getCertificateChain(keyAlias);



        /*
         * INSTANCIAMOS EL CERTIFICADO DE IVAN
         */        
        InputStream fr =  Pivote.class.getResourceAsStream(args[3]);
        CertificateFactory cf =  CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        X509Certificate crt = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(fr);

        /*
         * 
         */

        //
        // create the generator for creating an smime/encrypted message
        //
        SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator  gen = new SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator();          
        gen.addKeyTransRecipient(crt);
        //gen.addKeyTransRecipient((X509Certificate)chain[0]);



        //
        // create a subject key id - this has to be done the same way as
        // it is done in the certificate associated with the private key
        // version 3 only.
        //
        /*
        MessageDigest           dig = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1", "BC");

        dig.update(cert.getPublicKey().getEncoded());

        gen.addKeyTransRecipient(cert.getPublicKey(), dig.digest());
        */

        //
        // create the base for our message
        //
        MimeBodyPart    msg = new MimeBodyPart();

        msg.setText("¿PUEDEN VER ESTA PARTE DEL MENSAJE?");

        MimeBodyPart mp = gen.generate(msg, SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator.RC2_CBC, "BC");
        //
        // Get a Session object and create the mail message
        //
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", args[2]);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        Address fromUser = new InternetAddress(args[4]);
        //Address toUser = new InternetAddress(args[5], false);

        MimeMessage body = new MimeMessage(session);
        body.setFrom(fromUser);
        //body.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toUser);
        body.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, args[5]);
        body.setSubject("Confirmar si ven mensaje, por favor " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
        body.setContent(mp.getContent(), mp.getContentType());
        body.saveChanges();
        body.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("encrypted.message"));

        /*
         * Firmo el mensaje
         */
        EncryptionUtils smimeUtils = EncryptionManager.getEncryptionUtils(EncryptionManager.SMIME);    
        EncryptionKeyManager smimeKeyMgr = smimeUtils.createKeyManager();
        smimeKeyMgr.loadPrivateKeystore(Pivote.class.getResourceAsStream("ITtest.p12"), "pass".toCharArray());
        Key privateKey = smimeKeyMgr.getPrivateKey((String)smimeKeyMgr.privateKeyAliases().iterator().next(), "pass".toCharArray());
        smimeUtils.signMessage(session, body, privateKey);
        /*
         * Fin de firja
         */


        Transport.send(body);

        System.out.println("Mensaje enviado");
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Changing output encryptor to AES256_CBC did the trick for me.

```
MimeBodyPart mp = gen.generate(msg, SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator.AES256_CBC, "BC");
```

Comment: Thanks ! I do not remember what was the solution but I think I was something like that !